# How to rotate coordinates on a sphere by 90 degrees?

Tags: r, geometry, coordinates, rotational-matrices, cartesian-coordinates

I have a number of coordinates (representing electrodes on an EEG-cap) on a sphere. I have their position in both cartesian and spherical coordinates.

```
   chan         X         Y     Z   long   lat sph_radius
1   Fp1  8.08e+01  2.61e+01 -4.00   17.9 -2.70         85
2   Fp2  8.08e+01 -2.61e+01 -4.00  -17.9 -2.70         85
3    F3  5.76e+01  4.82e+01 39.90   39.9 28.00         85
4    F4  5.76e+01 -4.81e+01 39.90  -39.9 28.00         85
5    C3  3.87e-15  6.32e+01 56.90   90.0 42.00         85
6    C4  3.87e-15 -6.32e+01 56.90  -90.0 42.00         85
7    P3 -5.76e+01  4.82e+01 39.90  140.0 28.00         85
8    P4 -5.76e+01 -4.81e+01 39.90 -140.0 28.00         85
9    O1 -8.08e+01  2.61e+01 -4.00  162.0 -2.70         85
10   O2 -8.08e+01 -2.61e+01 -4.00 -162.0 -2.70         85
11   F7  4.99e+01  6.84e+01 -7.49   53.9 -5.06         85
12   F8  4.99e+01 -6.84e+01 -7.49  -53.9 -5.05         85
13   T3  5.18e-15  8.45e+01 -8.85   90.0 -5.97         85
14   T4  5.18e-15 -8.45e+01 -8.85  -90.0 -5.97         85
15   T5 -4.99e+01  6.84e+01 -7.49  126.0 -5.06         85
16   T6 -4.99e+01 -6.84e+01 -7.49 -126.0 -5.05         85
17   Fz  6.07e+01  0.00e+00 59.50    0.0 44.40         85
18   Cz  5.20e-15  0.00e+00 85.00    0.0 90.00         85
19   Pz -6.07e+01 -7.44e-15 59.50 -180.0 44.40         85
```

I want to rotate all electrodes by 90 degrees counterclockwise/downwards on the z-axis, so that electrode Cz, which is now (long = 0, lat =90), becomes (long= 0, lat=0). I don't care whether the rotation is performed on the cartesian or spherical coordinates as I can easily convert one into the other.

I have tried to find a solution for this problem on this site, but they were all overwhelming. If anyone could offer a simple R formula to get this rotation done, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think your rotation is poorly defined. Picture the earth and imagine a point at the north pole (with z-axis running through the north and south poles). If you want to rotate this point 90 degrees down, any point on the equator is a valid result. If you can define your rotation better [wikipedia's page section on 3d rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) should help you formulate the correct matrix to multiply by.

Comment: @dww I think your answer was useful, but no I don't think OP isn't thinking about the axis to rotate around. The example `(long = 0, late = 90) |--> (long = 0, lat = 0)` suggests mapping orthogonal to the z-axis, but orthogonal *how* seems poorly defined.

Comment: as @Gregor pointed out, this rotation confuses me a bit. I suggest you to define first the reference system, and the rest will be easier: in the common way "we" think about Earth, XY is the plane in which the equator is, XZ is the plane in which Greenwich meridian is, X axis contains the point with both latitude and longitude equal to zero. In this reference system, a rotation around Z involves only longitude (Earth rotation motion), a rotation around Y involves only latitude (Earth inclination), a rotation around X involves both values.

Answer (score 1):

using your lat/long coordinates (in data.table notation)

```
# 1st we deal with cases where lat>0, 
# i.e. rotation does not entail passing through the south pole
dt[, long.rot := long] # longitude stay in the same plane as we rotate 
dt[, lat.rot := lat-90] # latitude moves south 90 degrees

# now we deal with case that were already in the southern hemisphere,
# which will rotate through the south pole and northwards on the opposite longitude
dt[lat < 0,  long.rot :=  -sign(long)*(180-abs(long)) ]
dt[lat < 0,  lat.rot := 180+lat.rot ]
```

However, a word of warning: points at, or close to the north pole may behave unexpectedly.  Strictly speaking, longitude at the pole is undefined and should be given as NA. In this case, the rotated longitude will be NA, as the 'rotated' point could be at any unspecified location on the equator.

For points close to the poles, although the longitude is mathematically well defined, small uncertainties in the location will be magnified into large uncertainties in the location of the rotated points around the equator

Comment: I do still like this and think it's useful, but I think you should add in some words of warning. This isn't a rotation by any conventional definition - it doesn't preserve distance between points (a small circle of equally spaced points around the north pole will be mapped to giant circle close to the equator), and all points will be mapped to the southern hemisphere. It still might be what OP wants, but it isn't a rotation.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor, I've added these cautionary notes in

Answer (score 0):

You must take into consideration that 1 degree N/S is different of 1 degree W/E, depending on the latitude.

Consider 1 degree W/E at equator equals to X, and at a pole, its 0. So, 1 degree of longitude equals to X * Cos(latitude).

So this is the transformation you are looking for:

```
double x = pivot.lng; // Pivot coordinate
double y = pivot.lat; // Pivot coordinate
double cx = ((location.lng - pivot.lng) * 1852 * 60); // Horizontal distance in metres to pivot
double cy = ((location.lat - pivot.lat) * 1852 * 60 * Math.Cos(location.lat * Math.PI / 180); // Vertical distance in metres to pivot
double theta = -rotation * Math.PI / 180; // Angle, in radians

double x1 = cx * Math.Cos(theta) - cy * Math.Sin(theta); // Rotated cx
double y1 = cx * Math.Sin(theta) + cy * Math.Cos(theta); // Rotated cy

location.lat = y + (y1 / 1852 / 60);  // Rotated latitude, from metres to degrees
location.lng = x + (x1 / 1852 / 60 / Math.Cos(y * Math.PI / 180)); // Rotated longitude, from metres to degrees
```

Just a heads up this is still aproximate, since if the latitudinal distance from the pivot point to the point you want to rotate is too big, there will be some artifacts.